# Missing Fields on Power BI from MS Dynamics CRM Data

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerbi

With Power BI Desktop, several fields are missing when I connect via Dynamics CRM Online, in various entities. For example, LeadSet is missing Status and Status Reason. Why?

I need to create a report for my organization that shows leads by their status and status reasons but these aren't showing.

I'm connecting through this link "https://myorganization.crmXX.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc"

Trying to search online for answers around this isn't bringing back much - hoping someone on here can help.

Comment: I've found that I can see the Status and Status reason fields on app.powerbi.com but there are some options that I've added to the status reason which aren't showing such as "Size > 250" or "Outsourced". - Where am I getting these inconsistencies from, what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Could you post a bit more information? Maybe few example lines of your csv including headers, your dataset import string, screenshots of where missing fields or reports should be.